# Having Problems configuring Sharethis Module with Drupal 6

Tags: social-network

Firstly, this is my first post in this forum so if I am posting in the wrong place or anything similar then please point me in the right direction!

What I have is the Sharethis module - http://drupal.org/project/sharethis

Basically it is easily to setup (by the looks of things) in Drupal 7 by clicking on configure, whereas Drupal 6 on the other hand only has a box where I can paste 'custom code' into.

If I work through the configuration on the site - http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools# -and select website I get some custom code consisting of a set of spans and 2 scripts to add in my header.

What I have done is added the span code to the custom code box and placed both scripts in the header section of my page.tpl.php file, yet it doesn't seem to work. I can't seem to find any documentation on sorting this out in Drupal 6 neither, as it all points back to how to set it up in 7 (Very frustrating!)

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: the same seems to be in my case with Drupal 6, except that not using any code applies a default share this in my selected nodes in link region as configured, I've added a [Support Request](https://drupal.org/node/1921194) for more clarity on the module in the issue list, hopefully some response might ensue.. also the second script that gets generated with some json options needs to be at the footer of the page and not the header (suggest using drupal_add_js() than coding into the tpl files).. hope that helps for the time being